# Combine Get-ChildItem and Test-Path - Rewrite cmd/batch to PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I currently try to move some old cmd/batch scripts to PS, finally! Currently I have a script that finds all .bak-files and creates a 7ziped file along with it if it does not exist.

My current script looks like this:

```
for /R "E:\Backup" %%f in (*.bak) do (
    echo %%f
    if not exist "%%f.7z" (
        7Z a "%%f.7z" "%%f"
    )
)
```

So I’m trying to rewrite in PS.

This will give me the list of all .back-files, but how do I add .7z to the filename and test it it does exist (Test-Path):

```
$path = "E:\Backup"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.bak | Test-Path -Path %{$_.FullName} # Add .7z here?
```

And in the next step I’ll run the command to create the 7z-file:

```
7z.exe a "file.bak.7z" "file.bak"
```

Should I store all found files in an array and iterate the array, or should I use the ‘|’ to chain the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't test, but something like this should work

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.bak' -File -Recurse |
Foreach-Object { 
    $zip = $_.FullName + '.7z'
    If (!(Test-Path -Path $zip -PathType Leaf)) {
        # create the zip file
        7z.exe a $zip $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Theo,
I learned allot here!

My final PS looks like this:

```
$path = "E:\Backup"
$7z = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$filter = "*.bak"

# Compress files not already compressed.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter -File -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
    $archive = $_.FullName + '.7z'
    If (!(Test-Path -Path $archive -PathType Leaf)){
        & @7z a "$archive" "$($_.FullName)"
    }
}
```